# How classes work in a CSS file?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to figure out exactly how classes working in a CSS files.  Here are 3 example classes:

```
container
inner_content
text_section
```

Here are three ways I've seen those listed in the CSS:

`.container.inner_content.text_section {`  - This one has no spaces between the classes.

`.container .inner_content .text_section {`  - This one has spaces between the classses.

`.container li.inner_content`  - This one has `li` thrown into the middle of it.

What I'm trying to find out is what's the difference between having spaces or not having spaces between the classes.  Also, when stuff like `li` or `div` is in the middle of the classes, is it telling the browser to only use that class if it's for an `li` or `div` but not for anything else?

Comment: There are umptillion tutorials on the web that explain how CSS selectors work. -1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your first example:

`.container.inner_content.text_section`

Match any element that has all three classes

```css
.container.inner_content.text_section {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container inner_content">one class</div>
<div class="container inner_content">two classes</div>
<div class="container inner_content text_section">all three classes</div>
```

Your second example is totally different:

`.container .inner_content .text_section`

Match any element that is a descendant of an element with class `.container` and also descendant of an element with class `.inner_content` (that is: a child, or a child of a child, etc.):

```css
.container .inner_content .text_section {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  not this
  <div class="inner_content">
    not this
    <div class="text_section">child</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And in your last example:

```
.container li.inner_content
```

Match a `li` element that has class `inner_content` and is child of an element with class `.container` (suppose a `ul` element):

```css
.container li.inner_content {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul class="container">
  <li>1</li>
  <li class="inner_content">2</li>
  <li>3</li>
</ul>
```